# automatically redirect from form insert view to form result view with the data inserted in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am developing a student management system where the problem is that i want to redirect it in the result view (function viewAssessedStudent) all I want is that after you save the data in the insert view( function assessment) it will redirect to the Result view with the information i inserted in the insert view.

PS. I am using Codeigniter activerecord...

Controller

```
function assessment($id) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('top_menu', 'Student Information');
    $this->session->set_userdata('sub_menu', 'student/assessment');

    $data['title'] = 'student Assessment';

    $student_result = $this->student_model->get();
    $data['studentList'] = $student_result;

    $session_result = $this->session_model->get();
    $data['sessionList'] = $session_result;

    $class = $this->class_model->get();
    $data['classlist'] = $class;

    $feesdiscount_result = $this->feediscount_model->get();
    $data['feediscountList'] = $feesdiscount_result;

    $feegroup_result = $this->feesessiongroup_model->getFeesByGroup($fee_group_id);
    $data['feegroupList'] = $feegroup_result;

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_id', 'Student Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('class_id', 'Grade Level', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fee_session_group_id', 'Payment Method', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
     $this->load->view('layout/header', $data);
     $this->load->view('student/studentAssest', $data);
     $this->load->view('layout/footer', $data);
    } else {
        $session_id = $this->input->post('session_id');
        $student_id = $this->input->post('student_id');
        $class_id = $this->input->post('class_id');
        $feegroup_id = $this->input->post('fee_session_group_id');
        $discount_id = $this->input->post('fees_discount_id');
        $discount_amount = $this->input->post('std_discount');
        $insert_array = array(
           'session_id'       => $session_id,
           'student_id'       => $student_id,
           'class_id'         => $class_id,
           'assessment_date'  => $this->input->post('assessment_date')
        );
        $studentSession_id = $this->assessment_model->add($insert_array);

        $fee_data = array(
            'student_session_id' => $studentSession_id,
            'fee_session_group_id' => $feegroup_id,
        );
        $this->studentfeemaster_model->add($fee_data);

        $discount_data = array(
            'student_session_id' => $studentSession_id,
            'fees_discount_id' => $discount_id,
            'std_discount' => $discount_amount,
        );
        $this->feediscount_model->allotdiscount($discount_data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-left">Student Assessed Successfully</div>');
        redirect('student/assessment');  
    }
}

  function viewAssessedStudent($id){

    $data['title'] = 'Student Details';
    $student = $this->student_model->getAssesstStudent($id);
    $gradeList = $this->grade_model->get();
    $student_session_id = $student['student_session_id'];
    $student_due_fee = $this->studentfeemaster_model->getStudentFees($student['student_session_id']);
    $student_discount_fee = $this->feediscount_model->getStudentFeesDiscount($student['student_session_id']);
    $data['student_discount_fee'] = $student_discount_fee;
    $data['student_due_fee'] = $student_due_fee;


    $data['gradeList'] = $gradeList;
    $data['student'] = $student;
    $this->load->view('layout/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('student/studentShowAssess', $data);
    $this->load->view('layout/footer', $data);
}
```

insert View

```
 <form action="<?php echo site_url("student/assessment") ?>"  id="employeeform" name="employeeform" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="pull-right box-tools col-md-3" style="position: absolute;right: 14px;top: 13px;">
                       <select  id="session_id" name="session_id" class="form-control" >

                                                <?php
                                                foreach ($sessionList as $session) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $session['id'] ?>" <?php
                                                    if (set_value('session_id') == $session['id']) 
                                                    {
                                                        echo "selected =selected";
                                                    }
                                                    ?>><?php echo $session['session']?></option>
                                                            <?php
                                                            $count++;
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                        </select>

                    </div>                    
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="tshadow mb25 bozero">
                            <h3 class="pagetitleh2">Assess <?php echo $this->lang->line('student'); ?></h3>
                            <div class="around10">
                                <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('msg')) { ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg') ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php echo $this->customlib->getCSRF(); ?>
                                <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-bottom: 25px;">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
                                 <img class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-square" src="<?php echo base_url() . $student['image'] ?>" alt="User profile picture">
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                   <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Select Student</label>
                                            <select  id="student_id" name="student_id" class="form-control" >
                                                <option value="">Select Student</option>
                                                <?php
                                                foreach ($studentList as $student) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $student['id'] ?>" <?php
                                                    if (set_value('student_id') == $student['id']) {
                                                        echo "selected =selected";
                                                    }
                                                    ?>><?php echo $student['lastname'] . ", " . $student['firstname'] . " " . $student['middlename'] ?></option>
                                                            <?php
                                                            $count++;
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                                            </select>
                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('student_id'); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Grade Level Applying</label>
                                            <select  id="class_id" name="class_id" class="form-control" >
                                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('select'); ?></option>
                                                <?php
                                                foreach ($classlist as $class) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $class['id'] ?>" <?php
                                                    if (set_value('class_id') == $class['id']) {
                                                        echo "selected =selected";
                                                    }
                                                    ?>><?php echo $class['class'] ?></option>
                                                            <?php
                                                            $count++;
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                                            </select>
                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('class_id'); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                   <div class="col-md-2" hidden="true">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Assessment Date</label>
                                            <input id="assessment_date" name="assessment_date" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('assesstment_date', date($this->customlib->getSchoolDateFormat())); ?>" readonly="readonly" />
                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('assessment_date'); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Mode of Payment</label>
                                                        <select class="form-control" id="fee_session_group_id" name="fee_session_group_id">
                                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                                             <?php
                                                foreach ($feegroupList as $feegroup) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $feegroup->id ?>" <?php
                                                    if (set_value('fee_session_group_id') == $feegroup->id) {
                                                        echo "selected =selected";
                                                    }
                                                    ?>><?php echo $feegroup->group_name ?></option>
                                                            <?php
                                                            $count++;
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('fee_session_group_id'); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Payment Discount</label>
                                             <select  id="fees_discount_id" name="fees_discount_id" class="form-control" >
                                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('select'); ?></option>
                                                <?php
                                                foreach ($feediscountList as $feeDiscount) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $feeDiscount['id'] ?>" <?php
                                                    if ($feeDiscount['feediscount_id'] == $feeDiscount['id']) {
                                                        echo "selected =selected";
                                                    }
                                                    ?>><?php echo $feeDiscount['name'] ?></option>
                                                            <?php
                                                            $count++;
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Discount Amount</label>
                                            <input id="std_discount" name="std_discount" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('std_discount'); ?>" />
                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('std_discount'); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>    
                        </div>         
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Save Assestment</button>
                        </div>
                </form>
```

Result View

```
                        <div class="col-md-10 pull-right" style="padding-top: 25px;">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Student Last Name</label>
                                            <input id="student_id" name="student_id" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo set_value('student_id', $student['lastname']); ?>" />

                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('student_id'); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Student Last Name</label>
                                            <input id="student_id" name="student_id" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo set_value('student_id', $student['firstname']); ?>" />

                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('student_id'); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Student Last Name</label>
                                            <input id="student_id" name="student_id" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo set_value('student_id', $student['middlename']); ?>" />

                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('student_id'); ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Grade Level Applied</label>
                                            <input id="class_id" name="class_id" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo set_value('class_id', $student['class']); ?>" />

                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('student_id'); ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Assessment Date</label>
                                            <input id="assessment_date" name="assessment_date" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo set_value('assessment_date', $student['assessment_date']); ?>" />

                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('assessment_date'); ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Registration Date</label>
                                            <input id="admission_date" name="admission_date" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo set_value('admission_date', date($this->customlib->getSchoolDateFormat(), $this->customlib->dateyyyymmddTodateformat($student['admission_date']))); ?>" />

                                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('admission_date'); ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[This is the insertView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB347.jpg)
[this is the resultView and I want to redirect in this view after I saved the information in the insertView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4g4N.jpg)

Comment: what's the problem you're having?

Comment: I want to redirect to the result view my please check this code in the last part of the viewAssessedStudent function in my controller the code is redirect('student/assessment'); i change it to redirect('student/viewAssessedStudent'); the problem is that in the url i have to redirect in the student_id like this one http://localhost/pms/student/viewAssessedStudent/10 the 10 is the id of the student in the database the problem is that i want to redirect it in the id number of the student using my code

Comment: when i click submit it only redirects me in the url http://localhost/pms/student/viewAssessedStudent/   the id number of the student do not appear in the url

Comment: The redirect will take the actual url you are trying to visit, not a method name. Can you not do: `redirect('student/assessment/'.$student_id);`  ?

Comment: Thank you very much @dgig i got an idea on how to resolve it and it works to me. I just change the assessment to viewAssessedStudent just like this 
          redirect('student/viewAssessedStudent/'.$student_id); once again thank you very much for your help

Comment: great, glad it worked.